# I can't access my USB device after mkfs.ntfs command

Tags: usb, mkfs

I had used these commands (as root):

```
umount /dev/sdb1
```

After,

```
mkfs.ntfs /dev/sdb1
```

It took a long time to format it and I couldn't wait it. Before it finished formatting, I had canceled operation.

After I used my usb device for making copy operations, I couldn't use my usb device.

Actually, Maybe it wasn't about mkfs.ntfs command but there is a truth now:
I can't use my flash drive.

I plugged in my flash drive into my computer which uses linux mint. And I opened "Disks" program on Linux Mint. It is screenshot (after plugging in usb device):
[image: Disks Program - After plugging in usb device]

It is another screenshot (before plugging in usb device):
[image: Disks Program - Before plugging in usb device]

As you see, It says "No media" about /dev/sdb although I plugged in usb device.

There isn't any problem about my OS (Linux Mint). The problem is about my usb device. I can see my other usb devices on Linux Mint.

Have I burnt my usb device ?
How can I solve this problem ?

Edit: After intense desires of our participants , I should add it:

I used these commands (there are commands with outputs below):

```
LinuxMint linux # mkfs.ntfs /dev/sdb1
```

> Failed to access '/dev/sdb1': No such file or directory
>
> The device doesn't exist; did you specify it correctly?

```
LinuxMint linux # mkfs.ntfs /dev/sdb
```

> Could not open /dev/sdb: no media

So on, It can't recognize my usb device at all.

Look at fdisk output: Command:

```
fdisk -l
```

Output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, toplam 625142448 sektör
Units = sektör of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0007bccb

Device              Start         End     Sectors Size   Type
/dev/sda1            2048   251660287   125829120   83   Linux
/dev/sda2       251660288   541255679   144797696    5   Extended
/dev/sda3 *     541255680   619380679    39062500   83   Linux
/dev/sda4       619380736   625141759     2880512   82   Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda5       251662336   335548415    41943040   83   Linux
/dev/sda6       335550464   457369599    60909568   83   Linux
/dev/sda7       457371648   541255679    41942016   83   Linux
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and add the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sdb` (as `root`) with your flash drive plugged in? If it shows a partition, try running `mkfs.ntfs` again...

Comment: There is no any output.

Answer (score 1):

You started creating a filesystem on your device and cancelled the operation. That left your device with no working file system so, of course, you can't use it.

The good news is that, unless you've done something else you haven't told us about, it should be enough to just plug the device in again and running

```
sudo mkfs.ntfs /dev/sdb1
```

This time, *let it finish*!

**Important**: before running the command above, make sure that the USB device you want to format is indeed `/dev/sdb`. That command will destroy any data present in `/dev/sdb` so if that's not your USB drive, you really don't want to run it.

Comment: I edited my question. Look at it.